# Version Controling on multiple versions of a winform app

Tags: winforms, version-control, tfs

I have two versions from a winform app:
a free version and a pro version.
sometimes I want to add a feature (or change) to both versions.
What is the easiest way to manage this changes on both version?
is there an easier way than TFS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the easiest way to manage this changes on both version?

Different branches for both versions (in any SCM), "Branch per Task" workflow (and finished task merged into needed branches, **no changes** performed in product-branches)

> is there an easier way than TFS?

You can use *any pure* VCS with good branching support (TFS is more than just VCS)

Comment: Thank you for answer! What VCS do you recommend for me? I work alone And (No team work) and local (No Need to internet) and i haven't worked with any vcs before!

Comment: @user2741577 - try SVN (TortoiseSVN), Mercurial (TortoiseHG), Fossil (as is, in CLI form) and define better **for you** and your habits - mileage may vary. I just don't recommend starting from Git and using Bazaar at all. For own different solo-projects I use Mercurial (now) mostly

Answer (score 1):

I would opt for having a single code base and using conditional compilation to produce the two versions. This way you do not even think of managing branches to separate free from pro.